# How can I use the conditional ～ば and desiderative ～たい together?

Tags: conjugations, conditionals, auxiliaries

I think the title is self-explanatory.

I've been wondering how to combine the desiderative (たい) and the conditional (えば/たら).
For example, if I want to say "Excuse me, what should I do if I want to smoke here", it thought it would translate to "失礼{しつれい}ですがここでたばこを吸{す}いたければどうしたらいいですか", however I'm not sure whether that's correct or not. Also, if possible, could someone also provide a few examples of how to use both たい+えば and たい+たら so I could grasp the difference and meaning properly?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're correct except it's たければ and たかったら.

Comment: FWIW, the **volitional** is generally the label used for the //oː// ending, as in たべよう or いこう.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Volitional,_presumptive,_or_hortative.  The たい ending is more commonly called the **desiderative**.  See the table in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Japanese_verbs#Inflected_forms.

Comment: That's a weird statement. "What should I do to smoke here?" Does this involve illegal drugs? What's wrong with just saying ここで吸ってもいいですか?

Comment: @broccoliforest yeah I wrote え　instead of れ　by accident. Also, thank you very much.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Thank you very much, I'll make sure I check them out.

Comment: @Fireheart251 What I wanted to say was "what should I do if I want to smoke here" because while I was in Japan I would very often want to smoke, however I was unsure if I was allowed to smoke there, and if not, whether there was a smoking area nearby, so I thought that question would get me the answer I needed.